# Configuration tags, [tag:customise], and related

Tags: discussion, tags

We have several tags that are variants on [customise](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customise) and [configure](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configure). I don't see these categories being useful, as the questions are already grouped by their subject (the program being customized/modified), while user expertise in customization qua customization doesn't make sense.

At first I considered a rename/merge to [configuration](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) until I saw the above issue. If there was demonstrated need, we could have a [configure-scripts](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configure-scripts), but I don't see a pertinent use case for [configuration](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration). If you disagree, at the very least we should merge the configure/customise tags into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configure, customise, and customize will now all merge to [configuration](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration)

Comment: Do you think the combined tag will be useful? It currently looks like a hodgepodge of things that more have to do with settings than necessarily configuration files (and are better covered in other tags)

Comment: Configuration in general is messy. I think it's best we don't encourage the use of several different and poorly defined tags though. We should encourage people to tag the application/area they want to configure as well.

Comment: All right, but raising the possibility of just deleting it outright

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way for me to quickly delete a tag.

Comment: Probably worth merging [tag:configuration] with [tag:settings] too—they overlap in scope (unless you think that requires another discussion)